# Too Many Printer Redirection Ports on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, printing

We have a Windows 2008 R2 server with Printer Redirection, that clients connect to via Remote Desktop/Terminal Services. When there are a lot of users logged in to the server simultaneously, many of them can't see or print to their local (client) printers.

We have enabled local group policy "Redirect only the default client printer" on both computer and user level, and the user can only "see" his or her default client printer. But, every user *still* gets a redirection port to *every* local printer (in the Registry).

With 100 simultaneous users, this translates to more than 600 redirected, active ports.

How can we make Windows only allocate printer redirection ports to the default printers? (Why is this even a problem, why is 600 printer ports such a huge problem for Windows?) Would more RAM mitigate the problem?

(We have installed [the hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2655998) and tried the Fix It application, but the problem doesn't seem to be due to inactive ports, but too many active ones.)

**Update:** The server is running inside VMWare.

Comment: You have 100 users connecting to 1 Windows 2008 R2 server?

Comment: Yes, is that maybe not a good idea? Is there some kind of recommendation?

Comment: How much memory do you have on that server? What does the utilization look like on the server? What version of VMWare are you using?

Comment: Not sure about VMWare version, but RAM is currently only at 8 GB. At peak times, almost 7.5 is used...

Answer (score 1):

What drivers are you using? [Easy Print](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519199%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)? If you're not, or if the client doesn't support that, you're going to have to install the print driver on your server. Yes, for each of your 100 users.